# How to push a value to an array value in a hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I'm trying to set different arrays as the values of a hash using a range, then push a value into one of the arrays. I want this outcome:

```
hash[0] << 3 
hash #=> {0=>[3], 1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}
```

I did this:

```
hash = Hash[(0..9).to_a.product([Array.new(0)])]
#=> {0=>[], 1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[], 4=>[], 5=>[], 6=>[], 7=>[], 8=>[], 9=>[], 10=>[]}
hash[0] << 3 #=> [3]
hash #=> {0=>[3], 1=>[3], 2=>[3], 3=>[3], 4=>[3], 5=>[3], 6=>[3], 7=>[3], 8=>[3], 9=>[3], 10=>[3]}
```

I assume the reason I get the output is because all my keys are referencing the same array instead of different arrays.

How could I get the expected outcome?

Comment: Could you state the question?

Comment: edited hope thats more clear

Comment: On a side note if this is our actual expectation a `Hash` seems unnecessary since `hash[0]` would be the same if it was a `Hash` or an `Array` and the `Array` could be constructed as `Array.new(10)  { [] }`

Comment: very true @engineersmnky I suppose it would be redundant to make it a hash.

Comment: update: @engineersmnky but I remembered why the hash was necessary; the ranges are not always 0..9 in a bucket sort I might need 10..19 range you see and an array index would not do that for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign a new array to each key. There are many ways of doing this. Here's a couple:

```
hash = (0..9).each_with_object({}) { |i, result| result[i] = [] }
hash = (0..9).map{|i| [i, []]}.to_h
```

Comment: These work, and are much easier to read than my hash creation. thank you for the help!

Comment: Or `Array.new(10) { |i| [i,[]]}.to_h`

Comment: /cc @engineersmnky  If ruby had a normal left-side curry, that might have been working: `{}.tap { |h| 10.times(&h.method(:[]=).curry(2).([])) }` :)

Comment: Also `(0..9).map(&Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=[]}.method(:[]))` would work.

Comment: This guy is pretending to be mudasobwa of the year : )

Comment: @engineersmnky my personal respect :)

Comment: @mudasobwa I deleted the previous version because we can feign left side curry like so `{}.tap {|h|

  10.times.with_object([], &h.method(:[]=))

}.transform_values(&:dup)` since with object will always pass the object as the last element

Comment: @engineersmnky you are killing me; aren’t you looking for a job in Barcelona [España, Europe :)] by any chance?